# Kentico V9 Confirm form submission with javascript history.back

Tags: kentico

My repeater has enough data where I see my pagination. When I view the detail transformation for any items after the first page, the history.back() button gives me the form submission error.

Short of hard coding the back button, what's the easiest solution to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the "history.back()" is your javascript?  The pagination is most likely occurring through postback, and any navigation back will require that same post data being sent.

One option is you can make the pagination not postback, but instead URL based.  In the "Paging" area of your repeater, set the Mode to "QueryString" and set a querystring key (like "page").  Try that!

Otherwise you will need to do a window.location = "/The/Previous/Url" so it won't event attempt a postback and will simply direct them to the page, but your page you were last on will be lost.

Comment: The pagination is post back to avoid reload. So there is a trade off. URL based paging it is, that way the user go back to 'page' they were on, and not the start of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the webpart in an update panel.  In the webpart you can check the box to do this very easy and leave the rest of your configurations the way they are.  If other elements on the page require a postback or rely on that webparts values then you may have to wrap all of them in an update panel.